# Trouble uploading PDF files from Angular to Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, http-status-code-500

I'm relatively new to Spring Boot and Angular and encountering difficulties with uploading PDF files from the frontend to the backend.

Spring Boot Service:

```
@Service
public class BankStatementService{


    public BankStatement uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        BankStatement bankStatement = new BankStatement();
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileType = file.getContentType();
        ServletUriComponentsBuilder downloadURl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath();
        long data = file.getSize();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            fileName = file.getName();

        }
        bankStatement.setFileName(fileName);
        bankStatement.setFileType(fileType);
        bankStatement.setData(data);
        bankStatement.setDownloadURl(downloadURl);
        return bankStatement;
    }
```

Spring Boot Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/upload",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE

)
public BankStatement uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    return bankStatementService.uploadFile(file);
}
```

Angular UploadService:

```
  uploadFile(file: File) {
    const formData = new FormData;
    formData.append('file', file);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      })
      
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl2 + 'upload', formData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Angular Upload Component.ts:

```
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit{
  uploadForm: FormGroup ;
  selectedFile: File | null = null;
  pdfUrl: string | null = null;

  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dataService : DataService) {
    this.uploadForm = this.fb.group({
      file: [null, [Validators.required]]
    })
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

onSelectFile(event: any): void {
    this.selectedFile= event.target?.files[0];
  
  }

  uploadFile(){
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      const formData = new FormData;
      formData.append('file',this.selectedFile.name)
      this.dataService.uploadFile(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('File uploaded successfully!', response);
         
          this.pdfUrl = response.url; 
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

And Here is the result that i got in the process:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJyB1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml7Xx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This line might be the problem?

Before:

```
const formData = new FormData;
```

After:

```
const formData = new FormData();
```